# ZF1: How to extend functionality of a parent class without modifying original source?

Tags: php, inheritance, zend-framework

I would like to add some functionality to the `Zend_Form_Element_Multi` class and have the `Select`, `Checkbox`, and `Radio` elements extend from that.  Is this possible without modifying the ZF source?

Answer (score 1):

creating your own base, then extend that per project, as shown in the code example below. This way if you want to add a new method to an object then you just need to add it to your own main object, leaving the core Zend object unmodified.

this is very good documentation to create our own class and extend zend form

just go throw [this link](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2012/07/31/custom-zend-framework-form-elements/)

**Edit**

Just go throw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944753/zend-form-element-multicheckbox-how-to-display-a-long-list-of-checkboxes-as-col) to manage extend functionality and use existing one also

Comment: thx but it still doesn't address the issue of extending the parent class Zend_Form_Element_Multi.  The example in the link only shows how to extend the child class of Zend_Form_Element_Select.  So I would have to duplicate the functionality that I want to add...

Comment: What if I want to add functionality that is not based on the view?  I'd like to truly extend the Zend_Form_Element_Multi class functionality.

Comment: you can use http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.decorators.html to add your custom function and use existing one